# Name for a set of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Im looking for some characteristics for the set of functions $\{f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$ such that there exists a sequence $t_k\rightarrow\infty$ (maybe not any sequence) such that $\int_0^{t_k}f$ converges.  The set obviously contains $L^1$ but more generally contain the functions that have the property $|\int_0^t f|<C$ for some constant C which depends only on $f$.

I would also be happy to look for characteristics of the latter set mentioned, i.e. $\{f\}$ such that $|\int_0^t f|<C$ for some C dependent only on $f$.